# Send local sqlite file to server

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have a database of many users,which i want to store on both locally and on my server.Whenever user updates any information,i successfully updates it in local database using core database. But how to change this information into the server?? I am not getting this please help?
I thinking of sqlite file to server every time user updates his information. but how to send data of sqlite file to server?

Comment: Are you using any webservices?

Comment: When the data is on the server, does it need to access/update the database, or is this just a backup copy that will only used on your iOS app?  (I am assuming the latter if it's CoreData).

Comment: I would look to just transfer the update, and not the whole sqlite file.

Comment: @Ajay No, my company has its own server.

Comment: @trojanfoe database on the server will be used as the main database, the core database is secondary. if the user has changed its settings while in offline mode then its changes will be changed automatically in core database, but when he will get access to internet, i want to change the previous settings that is present on the server with current settings in the core database that is present locally. How to do this?

Comment: @ophychius ok, can you tell exactly how to transfer even one record to the server. Suppose user want to change his password the how will i send the changed password to the server? Can you tell me the code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a column to your local DB that is the  last time updated.  (I think there may be a way to get SQLite to fill this in semi-automatically for you, but even doing it "manually" is no big deal.)  Then, when you want to upload updates, query for rows updated since the last upload.  Ship to the server as JSON records.

You can also keep a separate table that tracks updates, but that's for more complex scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use some tactics for this. Here is a short explanation of this work.

1. Database Structure
2. Web service

You have to design database at local and server side and manage flag(Bool) and update time.

1. Like when you launch app then you have to check your local data and take last update date and send request to server what's new update after this date. If there is any update then you can send data as a result of that webservice and handle that response at local device.
2. When you do some changes at local device then you have to manage flag, update time and created date. flag will show it has update on server or not. If updated then Y otherwise N. And you have to send created and updated date with this.

During this request you have to manage in a same timezone. You can use standard UTC timezone because there may be chances that User can switch in different timezones so handle this.

If you need more clarification then you can ask at our chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43424/coders-diary

This approach definitely work for you.

Comment: @ yes i think this is a better approach, send the updated fields instead  of whole sqlite file. Suppose if the user has changed the his password, then how will i send the updated password to the server. Can u tell me the code snippet for this? How to check that data has been received to the server? is there any delegate method which gets called?

Comment: No there is no delegate method. You have to develop some custom delegates to do this. For more info I have provided you my chat URL.